# Softmax with large number of classes?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Does using softmax with large number of classes (for example 10k) have any conceptual problems or numerical stability problems?

Answer (score 0):

Softmax itself will not occur any problem. However there will be a problem due to the network L2-norm error, if you real have a 10k classes to classify, which a small numerical fraction on the weights will cause a huge difference on latest layer output.